# how to get a child element from a listbox C# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I'm creating a list of images in a listbox, but i need the images to be clickable.

What I'm having trouble with is getting the value from the child element(textblock) when you click the image.

I have searched all over the net, but i cannot find the solution.

`

```
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>



    <StackPanel  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Tunga" FontSize="30" Foreground="White"  Text="WOW" />
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Tunga" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Text="Work Out Warz"  />
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Tunga" FontSize="36" Foreground="White"  Text="" Name="txtname" Height="45"/>
        <TextBlock FontFamily="Tunga" FontSize="25" Foreground="White" Text="" Name="txtwowid" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Grid  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" >
        <ListBox x:Name="LstImages" Background="Gray" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" Cursor="Hand" SelectionChanged="LstImages_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="10" >
                            <Button Click="Button_Click" >
                                <Image Source="{Binding img}" Height="250"/>
                            </Button>
                            <TextBlock Name="txtblname" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="White" FontSize="30" FontFamily="Tunga"/>                             
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

`

Comment: You are not able to get value because you are using ItemTemplate to create textblock inside the ListBox. The problem here is your listbox will create multiple instances of button and textblock without any reference to them. So accessing them would be a tedious job. But maybe you can check the return type of items in listbox, it will be of type content presenter. Try type casting them into textblock.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the selected item you can bind SelectedImage in your dataContext object which should have `Title` and `img` properties to SelectedItem property of ListBox

```
<ListBox SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedImage, Mode=TwoWay}" x:Name="LstImages" Background="Gray" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.PanningMode="HorizontalOnly" Cursor="Hand" SelectionChanged="LstImages_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
```